# What should we name our chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

A couple of us have stopped by our new chat room, and those of you who haven't should stop in and say "hi." Anyway, it needs a name. MSO has "Tavern on the Meta," SciFi is "Mos Eisley," what should we be?

- The Precipice
- The Edge
- Base Camp
- The Point of No Return
- The Campfire
- Fireside Chat
- The River
- The Lake

Just some ideas I'm throwing out, please do post other ideas if you have some.

Answer (score 9):

Why not just The Great Outdoors?

Comment: I'm a proponent of just naming chat rooms for their purpose. I can never find any other site's chat room with all their cutesie and insider joke-y names.

Answer (score 6):

My vote would be "Campfire" or "The Great Outdoors" :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm voting for "Base Camp" - since that is where we sit and plan our next move... Anything relating to "fire" although outdoorsy sounding has the unfortunate assumption that fire is a foundation of the outdoor experience.

Answer (score 3):

I like any of the first three, but I think `Fireside Chat` would be especially appropriate, since it is a "chat" room.

Comment: Fireside chat reminds me of grandma around the spinning wheel ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'd quite like a merge of two of the ideas there - "Campfire chat".