# Our chat room name

Tags: discussion, chat

I'm effectively reopening the question [What should we name our chat room?](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/what-should-we-name-our-chat-room)

So ours has been called **The Great Outdoors**. But well that's lame.....

So does anyone have any more interesting ideas on what the chat room should be called (You can add *The Great Outdoors* if you want).

Highest vote (that I like, this isn't a democracy) wins. Preference will be given to answers from people that actually participate in the chat room will be given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll suggest **The Base Camp** :D

Comment: I think I like this name most and I'm also very magnanimous like that...:)

Comment: Also who wants to enter a fire...? That'd be all burney and shiz.

Comment: @Liam: Thanks :-) Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

My Personal favourite is **The Camp Fire**

Comment: This discriminates against people who typically go outdoors in areas where campfires are prohibited! _(Just kidding, I think this is a great name.)_

Answer (score 3):

How about **The Mountain Hut** ?

Answer (score 0):

How about the **Geocafé**

(came at this from Geocache... not sure how much sense it makes...)

Comment: Bit specific to geocaching, maybe?